# Error while restoring the table dump

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqldump, mysql-5.7, ubuntu

> ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 25: Invalid default value for 'created_on'

I'm getting this error while restoring a table after taking the dump(remotely). I have used

```
 mysqldump -h (hostname) -u -p (dbname) (tablename) > dump.sql
```

and restored using

```
 mysql -u -p (dbname) < dump.sql.
```

Thank-you.

Comment: What is your sql_mode? Please check your current sql_modes by command:
show variables like 'sql_mode' ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your current sql_modes by command:

```
show variables like 'sql_mode' ;
```

**Or**

You can include SET statement, before you run any statements put this in the first line:

**`SET sql_mode = '';`**

Problem might be because of **sql_modes**.

So change it by remove the sql_mode **"`NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE`"** to make it work.

This is the default sql_mode in mysql new versions.